# GUI source IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, layout-manager

IntelliJ Idea GUI designer doesn't provide source code of generated JForm. I tried with File>Settings>GUI Designer> Java source Code, but there's no effect. What I get is something like this, and it looks different than on a preview.

```
private void $$$setupUI$$$() {
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager(1, 1, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), -1, -1));
    tabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
    panel1.add(tabbedPane1, new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_SHRINK | com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_GROW, com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_SHRINK | com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_CAN_GROW, null, new Dimension(200, 200), null, 0, false));
    final JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new com.intellij.uiDesigner.core.GridLayoutManager(1, 1, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), -1, -1));
    tabbedPane1.addTab("Log In", panel2);
    final JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
```

Also there is error warnings "cannot resolve symbol 'intellij'"
How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source generated by IDEA (as will be stated by a lot of the comments also output) isn't something that is meant to be edited.

It's unclear what was meant in your question regarding what looks different: Did you mean from how you think it should look given what the preview looks like? Or that the resultant gui that the code produces does look different ... if the later - please provide all source code to enable us to take a deeper look.

The warnings are because the classes (such GridLayoutManager) are not visible to the IDE/compiler until runtime.  However, if the program is run from IDEA - it should execute just fine since the forms_rt.jar (that contains this and other useful classes) will be present in the classpath.

Please see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/gui-designer.html for more details.